# ValueError: time data '2021-07-19 11:48:03.357+00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%Z' (match)

Tags: python, date, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

Help please. Can you let me know what's wrong with my format defined?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

df = pd.read_csv('timeseries.csv')
df.head()
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%Z')
X = df['timestamp']
y = df['time_minutes']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
reg = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)
reg.predict(X_test[1:2])
reg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

> ValueError: time data '2021-07-19 11:48:03.357+00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%Z' (match)

Comment: provide your code as well

Comment: `%Z` is for a timezone name. `%z` is for 4-digit timezone offsets. I don't think there's a format for 2-digit offsets like `+00`.

Comment: Put code in the question in a code block, not a comment.

Comment: Pandas recognizes the ISO8601 format. Have you tried using just `to_datetime(df['timestamp'])` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas should take care of that easily when you load your csv file, and you don't need to parse it later on :

```
df = pd.read_csv('timeseries.csv', parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Thank you. But Now I am facing another problem. Can you help me with this one too please? TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp' in time series forecast. All the code is same. I only changed one line to this X=df[['timestamp']] (to reshape array to 2D)

Comment: @FaribaLaiq that would be another question, please ask a new question and provide enough sample data/code

Comment: okay sure. I can post another question but after 90 mins. Thats why I asked.